# Magento2 : How to compile SCSS to CSS in Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, css, compilation, scss

Any one have idea How to compile SCSS to CSS in Magento2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting below error after run gulp styles

`/var/www/html/projectname/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15
      throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
      ^
Error: Missing binding /var/www/html/projectname/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 9.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running`npm install`.
Run`npm rebuild node-sass`to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/projectname/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/projectname/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/projectname/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:187:21)`

Comment: npm rebuild node-sass and try again

Answer (score 2):

you can follow these steps  to compile files with Gulp:

1.In magento root directory, create an empty package.json and copy-paste the following code:

```
 {
 "author": "Magento Commerce Inc.",
 "description": "Magento node modules dependencies for local 
 development",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "gulpfile.js",
 "dependencies": {
 "path": "^0.12.7"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "gulp": "^3.9.1",
 "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
 "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
 "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 }
}
```

2.Install Gulp by running the following command in a command prompt:

**npm install --save gulp-install**

3.Add the gulp-sass package for the Sass preprocessor by running the following command:

**npm install gulp-sass**

4.Create an empty gulpfile.js in your magento root directory and copy this code :

```
var gulp     = require('gulp'),
sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
notify       = require('gulp-notify');

var config = {
src           : 'app/code/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/*.scss',
dest          : 'app/code/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/'
};

// Error message
var onError = function (err) {
notify.onError({
title   : 'Gulp',
subtitle: 'Failure!',
message : 'Error: <%= error.message %>',
sound   : 'Beep'
})(err);

this.emit('end');
};

// Compile CSS
 gulp.task('styles', function () {
 var stream = gulp
.src([config.src])
.pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError));

return stream
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/code/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/'));
})
```

5.create a scss file in the app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/ directory.

6.Declare the resulting CSS file in the default_head_blocks.xml file in the app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

7.cd magento_root_directory and 
 run **gulp styles**

(the generated CSS styles.css in the app/code/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css directory)

I hope my answer was clear. Good luck and happy coding !!!

Comment: I know how to compile Less to CSS . My question is how to compile SCSS to CSS in magento2

Comment: @hweb87 sorry i updated my answer you can check

Comment: Error when run npm install --save gulp-install

npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token 
npm ERR!  in JSON at position 99 while parsing '{
npm ERR!  "author": "Magento Commerce Inc.",
npm ERR!  "'
npm ERR! File: /var/www/html/projectname/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

Comment: try to run npm cache clean before run npm install --save gulp-install

Comment: I have added error in comment

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on how it has been implemented it usually varies between:

- [Vanilla Sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass)
- [Gulp Sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)
- [Grunt Sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass)
- [Node Sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)
- [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)

I would start off with installing [Vanilla Sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass) and compiling with that, if you have errors I suspect it's a different method. To determine which one look for files such as `gulpfile.js`, `config.rb`, `packages.json`.

Welcome to the over-complicated world of front-end!

Comment: Hi @Ben thanks for reply, Is there any detailed documentation for that ?

Comment: For which one? If you click on the links I gave you there is documentation for each method. I can't find any guide on how to find out which method is used :( I could only confirm which method you need if I had visibility of the codebase.

Comment: We have purchased https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/62081.html this theme and it's in Magento ver. 2.2.4. I just want to know if I will change in SCSS thene how it's compile in CSS.

In Less I have run bin/magento set:up and it''s working fine

Comment: Hi Ben are you available in Slack ?

Comment: I will be in around 30 minutes, feel free to message me if you're on any of the Magento Slack groups and I'll get back to you when I'm free.

Comment: Sounds Good, I have message you in slack

Answer (score 0):

It's successfully compiled but can't changes in frontend

gulp style

```
[14:11:30] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/projectname/gulpfile.js
[14:11:30] Starting 'style'...
[14:11:30] Finished 'style' after 37 ms
```

Comment: try to run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Not working, but now process are correct, Right ?

Comment: did you check under  if your compiled file is generated under pub/static/frontend/../../../css/?

Comment: the process is correct refer to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/gulp-sass.html

Comment: Yes, But can't know why changes are not affect in frontend



I have changed in
app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme021/web/css/source/components/_rd-navbar.scss

but changes are not complied in
app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme021/web/css/style.css

Comment: File also generated in pub/static but not added new changes

Comment: yes you should modify your gulpfile.js because you only specified to compile scss files under app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme021/web/css and not under  app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme021/web/css/source/components

Comment: you should modify   gulpfile.js according to your needs. If my answer was helpful for you , you can kindly mark it as correct + vote to be helpful for others too

Comment: How to define components in gulp.js. do you have any idea ?

Comment: I think that you should modify like this : var config = {
src           : 'app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme021/web/css/source/component/*.scss',